# SqlAlchemy AsyncSession transaction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When using async session as context manager, what happens is if an exception raises, I get a warning that I wanna get rid of.
here's how I use the session:

```
async with session.begin():
    retailer: model.Retailer = (await session.scalars(select(model.Retailer).filter(model.Retailer.name=="default"))).first()
    await session.execute(insert(model.Contact).values(mock_contact(retailer.uuid)))
    raise RuntimeError()
```

and the warning that I get is:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Transaction.rollback' was never awaited
```

I'm sure what I'm supposed to do and the twist here should be a little tricky because I surfed the net for any possible solution and none worked

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Did you ever resolve it?  Please share your solution

Comment: Hi, yes. actually I managed to resolve it by reconsidering how I was using it. it wasn't sophisticated per se, just revise how you're working with the context manager. in my case I only had the issue during testing. by the way if needed more help just tell me